# Can I use a Postgres keyword as an alias in select list?

Tags: postgresql

I encountered a strange issue this morning. I was creating a view simplifying a list of applications in a Postgres table.

This failed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW application_view AS 
SELECT COALESCE( nullif(full_name,''), nullif(additional_info,''), app_name) name
, id
FROM application
ORDER BY COALESCE( nullif(full_name,''), nullif(additional_info,''), app_name)
```

whereas

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW application_view AS 
SELECT COALESCE( nullif(full_name,''), nullif(additional_info,''), app_name) application
, id
FROM application
ORDER BY COALESCE( nullif(full_name,''), nullif(additional_info,''), app_name)
```

worked.

I often use name as a column name in tables so any ideas as to why the first sql statement failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). When you want to use a keyword as an alias in the select list you have to use the word `as`:

```
select 1 name;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"
LINE 1: select 1 name;

select 1 as name;

 name 
------
    1
(1 row)
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html) about aliases in the select list:

> To specify the name to use for an output column, write AS *output_name* after the column's expression. (You can omit AS, but only if the desired output name does not match any PostgreSQL keyword  (see Appendix C). For protection against possible future keyword additions, it is recommended that you always either write AS or double-quote the output name.)

Comment: Thanks. I used to think the use of 'as' was optional in all cases.